# Use multiple css class together to <div></div>

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I want to use multiple css class together to

Each class is introduced in HTML as follows:

By doing so, each class in a row , I do not want.

I want come together in a row behind.

Each class is an animation ; In doing so, each in a paragraph &

Occupy much space.

css code :

```
.OT_below0 
{
border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;
border:solid transparent;
border:solid rgba(255,255,255,0);
border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
background:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/Index1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center center / cover;
background-attachment:fixed;
padding-top:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
height:700px;
}
 .spk1{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark1.png");
animation:spk1 30s infinite;
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk1 {
0%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
33%  {left:-10px;top:600px;}
66%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
100%  {left:-10px;top: 600px;}
}
.spk2
{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark2.png");
animation: spk2 50s infinite;
-webkit-animation: spk2 50s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk2 {
0%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
33%  {left:-10px;top:600px;}
66%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
100%  {left:-10px;top: 600px;}
}
.spk3
{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark3.png");
animation: spk3 60s infinite;
-webkit-animation: spk3 60s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk3 {
0%  {left:0px;top:0px;}
33%  {left:-1100px;top:500px;}
66%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
100%  {left:10px;top: -600px;}
}
.spk4
{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark4.png");
animation: spk4 120s infinite;
-webkit-animation: spk4 120s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk4 {
0%  {left:0px;top:230px;}
33%  {left:-1300px;top:290px;}
66%  {left:100px;top:210px;}
100%  {left:1250px;top: 250px;}
}
.spk5
{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark5.png");
animation: spk5 200s infinite;
-webkit-animation: spk5 200s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk5 {
0%  {left:-1300px;top:260px;}
50%  {left:50px;top:400px;}
100%  {left:-1300px;top: 600px;}
}
.spk6
{
width: 99px;
height: 99px;   
position: relative;
background-image:url("http://localhost/OTA/templates/OT/images/spark6.png");
animation: spk6 150s infinite;
-webkit-animation: spk6 150s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}
/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes spk6 {
0%  {left:0px;top:650px;}
33%  {left:-1300px;top:10px;}
66%  {left:150px;top:30px;}
100%  {left:-1350px;top: 650px;}
}
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="OT_below0"> </div>
<div class="custom"> </div>
<div class="spk1"> </div>
<div class="spk2"> </div>
<div class="spk3"> </div>
<div class="spk4"> </div>
<div class="spk5"> </div>
<div class="spk6"> </div>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a title="network" href="xx"><img  src="images/social/xx.png" alt="netw" width="90" height="90" /></p>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am very sorry your problem is not clear. Could you please try explaining a bit more what you trying to achieve? you can use a screenshot it it helps

Comment: I want the animation [link](http://www.hilux-co.com/index.php/about-us) But when I make the animation ,the distance between each image one line happens. As follows :
`<div class="spk1"> </div><br>
<div class="spk2"> </div><br>
<div class="spk3"> </div><br>
<div class="spk4"> </div><br>
<div class="spk5"> </div><br>
<div class="spk6"> </div>`

Comment: Hello ,
My problem was solved .
By putting `display: inline-block` in CSS code

Answer (score 0):

First: You must Make General Attributes CSS into A Keyframe, example:

```
@keyframes spkGeneral {
0%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
33%  {left:-10px;top:600px;}
66%  {left:-1100px;top:10px;}
100%  {left:-10px;top: 600px;}
}
```

You can set Multi Keyframes for an animation by:

```
   -webkit-animation-name: spkGeneral, spk1;
```